# Difference between viewing and download pdf file in java web app

Tags: pdf, spring-mvc, io, download

I need to have both the view and download .pdf file to use's computer functionality.
I am using Spring MVC 3 and view is as simple as pointing the url to the location of the file.

But I am not sure how to make that file downloadable. I am trying the code below for it but it seems to return nothing and the request never completes.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "files/{fileName}")
public void downloadPDF(@PathVariable("fileName") String fileName, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
    logger.debug("Http request URL is " + req.getRequestURL());
    res.setContentType("application/pdf");
    URL pdf = null;
    try {
        pdf = new URL(req.getRequestURL().toString());
        BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(pdf.openStream());

        IOUtils.copy(is, res.getOutputStream());
        res.flushBuffer();      
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Could someone understand why is it happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the header 'Content-Disposition' to the response if you want make the file downloadable.

The format of the header is:
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="fname.ext"

Try something like.

```
res.addHeader("Content-Disposition",  "attachment; filename=\"document.pdf\"");
```

Comment: Same result. The request just doesn't complete. Something wrong with my code in terms of downloading a file?

Comment: Try setting the content length header, with the length of the file.

Answer (score 1):

use below code :

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(..abcolute path...)));

response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\""+filename+".pdf"+"\"");
IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());     
              response.flushBuffer();
```

In my application it's working fine.